# How to use a sorted result as another MySQL syntax's `ORDER BY` basis?

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to use a sorted result as another MySQL syntax's `ORDER BY` basis?

For example,

I have queried the order of “records' repeat times”, which the records' column name is `country`. The SQL syntax is like below:

```
   SELECT country, count( * ) AS count

   FROM table1

   GROUP BY country

   ORDER BY count DESC
```

And the result is like below:

country                           count

======================

**United States**               13679

**United Kingdom**             8060

**Germany**                          6245

**Russian Federation**        6076

**Canada**                             3388

**Netherlands**                    4580

But now I want to list another data table which the `country_to_live` column is ordered by the result above. The syntax may be like below:

`SELECT name,age,salary FROM table2 ORDER BY (country_to_live ...)`

And the table2 may be like below:

name                         age                         salary                          country_to_live

============================================================

John                           25                              4000                          United States

Merry                          27                              3500                          United States

Bill                              26                              4200                          Germany

Jennifer                      26                              5000                          Netherlands

Abel                            34                              4700                          Canada

Leo                             31                              3400                          Russian Federation

Karen                         23                              7100                          United Kingdom

Sid                              35                              5600                          Canada

The result I want is like:



name                         age                         salary                          country_to_live

============================================================

John                           25                              4000                          **United States**

Merry                          27                              3500                          **United States**

Karen                         23                              7100                          **United Kingdom**

Bill                              26                              4200                          **Germany**

Leo                             31                              3400                          **Russian Federation**

Abel                            34                              4700                          **Canada**

Sid                              35                              5600                          **Canada**

Jennifer                      26                              5000                          **Netherlands**



So what is the `(country_to_live ...)`?

Comment: You can use 'SELECT name AS country_to_live, name, age, salary FROM' syntax.

Comment: But the `country_to_live` here is a column name. I'd want to use the first order that I had queried to order the `country_to_live` column.

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: You also use syntax SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER name) AS virtual_table;

Comment: E.g: `Select ... From ... X Join (select...as cnt Group by...) Y on y.country = X.country ORDER BY cnt DESC`

Comment: @mishanon In the absence of any user variables, an ORDER BY in a subquery is meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `count` result query to `join` with `table2` and `order` the results on `count`.

**Example**:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.age, t2.salary, t2.country_to_live
  FROM table2 AS t2
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS country_count
                FROM table1 GROUP BY country
            ) AS t1 ON t2.country_to_live = t1.country
 ORDER BY t1.country_count DESC, t2.name ASC;
```

Comment: Yes - but decide what the columns are called